# Full Join 5 different table in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have 5 different table with `col1`, `col3`, `col5`, `col7`, and `col9` are the ID such as below:

```
 Table 1        Table 2     Table 3     Table 4     Table 5 

col1 col2      col3 col4   col5 col6   col7 col8   col9 col10
 a    5         a    7      c    6      a    5      b     6
 b    7         b    8      f    2      c    6      c     7
 c    2         c    3      g    5      f    9      e     1
 e    5         d    7      h    8      g    3      f     5
 f    9         f    5      j    5      i    4      i     8
 g    3         g    1      k    2      k    6      
 h    6         h    9      l    6      n    1      
 j    1         i    7      n    8              
 k    5         j    4      o    3              
 m    6         k    7                      
 o    2         l    2                      
                n    5
```

I wanted to join all the tables regardless there have the same ID or not.

The result of the joined table should be like this:

```
col1 col2 col4 col6 col8 col10
 a    5    7         5  
 b    7    8              6
 c    2    3    6    6    7
 d         7            
 e    5                   1
 f    9    5    2    9    5
 g    3    1    5    3  
 h    6    9    8       
 i    1    7         4    8
 j    5    4    5       
 k         7    2    6  
 l         2    6       
 m    6             
 n         5    8    1  
 o    2         3
```

I have tried the query below but seems like any ID from Table 2, Table 3, Table 4 and Table 5 are not connected.

```
SELECT table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col4, table3.col6, table4.col8, table5.col10,
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col3
FULL JOIN table3 ON table1.col1 = table3.col5
FULL JOIN table4 ON table1.col1 = table4.col7
FULL JOIN table5 ON table1.col1 = table5.col9;
```

What is other way of join I should use to get the result as expected above?

Comment: MySQL does not implement FULL JOIN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
SELECT table0.col1,
       table1.col2,
       table2.col4,
       table3.col6,
       table4.col8,
       table5.col10
FROM (
    SELECT col1 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col3 FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col5 FROM table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col7 FROM table4
    UNION
    SELECT col9 FROM table5
    ) AS table0
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table0.col1 = table1.col1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table0.col1 = table2.col3
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table0.col1 = table3.col5
LEFT JOIN table4 ON table0.col1 = table4.col7
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table0.col1 = table5.col9
```

Comment: Shouldn't they all be UNION [DISTINCT]?

Comment: @jarlh Look - the most last UNION is distinct one. This will improve the query because this avoids excess sortings.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL do that transformation anyway?

Comment: @jarlh In this case MySQL works "as the query is written". Execute 1st SELECT, cache it. Execute 2nd SELECT and add to cache because of UNION ALL. The same for 3rd and 4th SELECTS. Then execute final SELECT, add to cache, sort and remove duplicates. If use UNION DISTINCT for all UNIONs then server will sort and remove duplicates after each SELECT. See https://dbfiddle.uk/e9v-Jqbc

Comment: @jarlh Exclusion - recursive CTEs with multiple recursive parts and ALL/DISTINCT mixing. According to the documentation the order of recursive subqueries execution is not defined (and you cannot predict where the intermediate rowset will be sorted - but in practice they're executed according to the query text nevertheless).